# Schedule a function to be enabled/disabled on certain days?

Tags: solidity

I have a function I need to  be enabled/disabled for certain address groups on certain weekends.

Say there are 2 groups. It alternates enabled on week 1 for group 1 and disabled for group 2.

I've been trying to use block.timestamp but can't figure out how I can do it. I also toyed with the idea of having 2 allow variables and going by days since the contract was deployed by that's even more confusing.

Is there an easy/possible way of doing this?

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: Nothing that came close to working. Using 2 variables from block.timestamp and offsetting one by 7 days but I can't figure out how to get the math unless I set a max amount of weeks.

Comment: I'd use a mapping address to group, then I'd use a setter function that will enable one group in particular. Each function will determine to which group does msg.sender belong and validate if that group is enabled.

Comment: That's not what I need to do but that is how I have part of my contracts. I need to figure out the math to disable for x days, enable for y; repeat.

Comment: That's completely unrelated to Ethereum. Since timestamp are unix use the fact that every day has 24 * 60 * 60 =  86400 seconds. Use that to convert a timestamp to days by dividing by 86400. Then calculate r = days % (x + y). Now if 0 <= r < x, you're on the first group, if x <= r < y then you're on the second group.

Comment: You may need to add a constant to days so r will be aligned to a particular day of the week.